# ymRuby on rails: Running specs for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm new to rspec framework, and I have a rails Application that I wish to use Rspec to write unit tests for it.
I followed the instructions in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails to install the rspec-rails gem.
I've written a very simple spec file that requires 'rails_helper' and have some pending tests only.

When I try to run this file using command `bundle exec rspec` I get this error

> An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/invoice_spec.rb.
>   Failure/Error: include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
>
> Mysql2::Error:
>    Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How do I resolve this so that I can run my specs?

Edit : database.yml file

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
username: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:mysql_db_user] %>
password: <%= Rails.application.secrets[:mysql_db_password] %>
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
<<: *default
database: tomav_dev

test:
<<: *default
database: tomav_test
```

Comment: How is your test db configured? Please share your `database.yml` file.

Comment: @Gerry, Just added the database.yml , thanks for responding.

Comment: does tomav_test db exists on your db?